# Размытие шрифтов в WPF на мониторах с разным DPI, подключенных к одному компьютеру

Tags: c#, wpf, .net-7, dpi

При разработке приложения на WPF (C#) столкнулся с проблемой отображения текста и других элементов управления. У меня основной монитор 4к, масштабирование 150%, второй монитор FHD, масштабирование 100%. При переносе окна приложения на второй монитор, отображение элементов искажается и становится размытым.

Пробовал следующие свойства для текста:

1. TextOptions.TextFormattingMode
2. TextOptions.TextRenderingMode
3. SnapToDevicePixels

К сожалению, ничего не помогло.

Пример отображения на мониторе 4к, 150%:
[image: 4к, 150%]

Пример отображения на мониторе FHD, 100%:
[image: FHD, 100%]

Версия .NET 7. На 5 и 6 была такая же проблема, но я на нее забил, так как не было времени ее решать.

Находил разные варианты решения проблемы, но ничего не помогало.
Прошу помочь тех, кто знает.

Comment: Версию дотнета используйте свежую (.NET 6 например), а не Framework 4, там поддержка HiDPI из коробки. При этом оно просто буднт само работать, и ничего дополнительно днлать не нужно. В Framework 4.x тоже можно включить, прописав DpiAwareness в manifest, но в рантайме смена DPI всё раано даст мыло, придется перезапускать приложение после смены DPI.

Comment: Прошу прощения, что не указал. Я использовал .NET 7. На 5 и 6 было также.

Comment: Ок, тогда я сдаюсь. Вероятно у WPF есть с этим проблемы. Возможно есть способ словить событие изменения DPI и вызвать полную переинициализацию интерфейса. Я сам сейчас под WinUI 3 пишу, проверял, там точно такой проблемы нет.

Comment: Сложно переучиться на WinUI 3? Я слышал, что это неплохой фреймворк для приложений под Wnidows 10 и 11

Comment: Сыроват пока, если честно. Переучиться не сложно, если хорошо знаете WPF, но там много всего странного и нового. Откройте Winfows Store и найдите приложение WinUI 3 Gallery, там показаны контролы и примеры.